# Store Stored Procedure return value using JPA

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use JPA (and Spring Boot 2) for executing a SQL Server stored procedure. Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetStatus] 
@statusId   char(32),
@bar    int
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT IIF(COUNT(1)>0 , 1, 0)   FROM Status WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE statusId = @statusId AND bar = @bar
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC EventLog @@PROCID
END CATCH
GO
```

I'm trying to capture the return value but can't find a way to do so. My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getStatusByStatusId",
                procedureName = "GetStatus",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "statusId", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "bar", type = Integer.class)                    })
})
public class Status implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Integer bar;
    private String statusId;
    private Date createDate;
}
```

And my repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<Status, Long> {
    @Procedure("GetStatus")
    int getStatusByStatusId(@Param("statusId") String statusId, @Param("bar") Integer bar);
}
```

When I run this method from the service layer, I get an error:

> "Parameter out was not defined for stored procedure..."

I tried to add out parameter (by naming it count and type as Integer). I tried List, Object[] but nothing worked.
Only thing that worked is if I change the repository method to return void. But in that case I can't get the return value.
So, my question is how can I get that SELECT value? Any help is appreciated. My app.yml has:

```
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://dev.lsd.com:1433;databaseName=Qrex;integratedSecurity=true;MultiSubnetFailover=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
    username:
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    database: sql_server
```

and my gradle dependency is:

```
compile "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.4.0.jre8"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that JPA can handle stored procedures returning an arbitrary number of result sets and/or update counts and/or error messages. All the examples I've seen are rather simplistic. Your procedure returns either:

- A result set containing a projection (not an entity!)
- Whatever the `EventLog` procedure returns. Could be anything

Here's how to do it with JDBC directly (there are no `OUT` parameters, so an ordinary `PreparedStatement` will do.

#### Here's how to fetch only one result set with JDBC:

```java
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "EXEC [GetStatus] ?, ?"
)) {
    stmt.setString(1, statusId);
    stmt.setInt(2, bar);

    if (stmt.execute()) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
            // Do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

#### Here's how to fetch an arbitrary number of result sets

In case you want to retrieve whatever `EventLog` produces as well, you might prefer calling this instead:

```java
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "EXEC [GetStatus] ?, ?"
)) {
    stmt.setString(1, statusId);
    stmt.setInt(2, bar);

    fetchLoop:
    for (int i = 0, updateCount = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        boolean result = (i == 0)
            ? s.execute()
            : s.getMoreResults();

        if (result)
            try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                System.out.println("Result      :");

                while (rs.next())
                    System.out.println("  " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        else if ((updateCount = s.getUpdateCount()) != -1)
            System.out.println("Update Count: " + updateCount);
        else
            break fetchLoop;
    }
}
```

[I've described this approach of fetching arbitrary result sets and update counts more in detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/07/13/how-i-incorrectly-fetched-jdbc-resultsets-again/), specifically also how to fetch exceptions and warnings correctly.

If you use that approach, you might want to wrap that logic in some library code.

#### Using jOOQ

There's also the possibility to use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) for these things (disclaimer: I work for the vendor), in case of which you could call:

```java
Results results = ctx.fetchMany("EXEC [GetStatus] ?, ?", statusId, bar);
```

To get an [`org.jooq.Results`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Results.html) type, which wraps interleaved result sets, update counts, exceptions, and warnings